# How can I detect if a user enters a string which does not follow my ANTLR grammar rules?

Tags: java, error-handling, antlr4

I am making a Computer Algebra System which will take an algebraic expression and simplify or differentiate it.

As you can see by the following code the user input is taken, but if it is a string which does not conform to my grammar rules the error,
line 1:6 mismatched input '' expecting {'(', INT, VAR}, occurs and the program continues running.

How would I catch the error and stop the program from running? Thank you in advance for any help.

Controller class:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String userInput = "x*x*x+";
        getAST(userInput);

    }

    public static AST getAST(String userInput) {
        ParseTree tree = null;
        ExpressionLexer lexer = null;
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(userInput);
        try {
        lexer = new ExpressionLexer(input);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect grammar");
        }
        System.out.println("Lexer created");

        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        System.out.println("Tokens created");
        ExpressionParser parser = new ExpressionParser(tokens);
        System.out.println("Tokens parsed");


        tree = parser.expr(); 

        System.out.println("Tree created");
        System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser)); // print LISP-style tree
        Trees.inspect(tree, parser);

        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        ExpressionListener listener = new buildAST();
        walker.walk(listener, tree);

        listener.printAST();
        listener.extractExpression();

        return new AST();
    }
}
```

My Grammar:

```
grammar Expression;

@header {
package exprs;

}
@members {
    // This method makes the parser stop running if it encounters
    // invalid input and throw a RuntimeException.
    public void reportErrorsAsExceptions() {
        //removeErrorListeners();

        addErrorListener(new ExceptionThrowingErrorListener());
    }

    private static class ExceptionThrowingErrorListener extends BaseErrorListener {
        @Override
        public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer,
                Object offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine,
                String msg, RecognitionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(msg);
        }
    }
}
@rulecatch {
    // ANTLR does not generate its normal rule try/catch
    catch(RecognitionException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

expr  : left=expr op=('*'|'/'|'^') right=expr 
      | left=expr op=('+'|'-') right=expr 
      | '(' expr ')' 
      | atom 
      ;

atom : INT|VAR;
INT   : ('0'..'9')+ ;
VAR   : ('a' .. 'z') | ('A' .. 'Z') | '_';

WS    : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Comment: You've defined a `reportErrorsAsException` method, but I don't see you calling it anywhere. Anyway, do you really want to abort parsing at the first syntax error? Or do you just want to prevent your listener from executing when there have been syntax errors?

Comment: @sepp2k I attempted trying to catch the error after various lines in the main class, but it didn't work. I want to completely abort, then run the program again, asking the user for a valid input.

Answer (score 0):

A typical parse run with ANTLR4 consists of 2 stages:

1. A "quick'n dirty" run with SLL prediction mode that bails out on the first found syntax error.
2. A normal run using the LL prediction mode which tries to recover from parser errors. This second step only needs to be executed if there was an error in the first step.

The first step is kinda loose parse run which doesn't resolve certain ambiquities and hence can report an error which doesn't really exist (when resolved in LL mode). But the first step is faster and delivers so a quicker result for syntactically correct input. This (JS) code shows the setup:

```
    this.parser.removeErrorListeners();
    this.parser.addErrorListener(this.errorListener);

    this.parser.errorHandler = new BailErrorStrategy();
    this.parser.interpreter.setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.SLL);

    try {
        this.tree = this.parser.grammarSpec();
    } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof ParseCancellationException) {
            this.tokenStream.seek(0);
            this.parser.reset();
            this.parser.errorHandler = new DefaultErrorStrategy();
            this.parser.interpreter.setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.LL);
            this.tree = this.parser.grammarSpec();
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

In order to avoid any resolve attempt for syntax errors in the first step you also have to set the `BailErrorStrategy`. This strategy simply throws a `ParseCancellationException` in case of a syntax error (similar like you do in your code). You could add your own handling in the catch clause to ask the user for correct input and respin the parse step.